(NODRIVER) how to send shortcut keys in an iframe
I've been trying to get my bot to press the Enter key and type in a box after going to the website "www.keyboardtester.com". It basically tracks if a key is pressed. I believe the bot cant find the iframe. I checked docs and support on git, but cant seem to figure it out. When I do it manually, it works fine. Has anyone faced a similar issue or have any insights on why the bot isn't finding the iframe?
import time
import asyncio
import nodriver as uc
from nodriver.cdp import fetch
from nodriver import *

async def website():
    browser_args = ['--disable-web-security', '--disable-site-isolation-trials']
    browser = await uc.start(browser_args=browser_args)
    
    try:
        tab = await browser.get("https://iframetester.com/?url=https://www.keyboardtester.com/tester.html")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)         

        # Select the iframe
        iframes = await tab.select('iframe')
        if iframes:
            iframe = iframes[0]
            
            # Now find the textarea inside the iframe
            input = await iframes.find("//textarea[@id='testarea']")
            if input:
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
                
                await input.send_keys("Test")
                
                # Simulate pressing Enter
                await input.send(uc.cdp.input_.dispatch_key_event(
                    type_="rawKeyDown",
                    windows_virtual_key_code=13,
                ))
                await input.send(uc.cdp.input_.dispatch_key_event(
                    type_="rawKeyUp",
                    windows_virtual_key_code=13,
                ))

                print('Entered')
            else:
                print("Unable to find text inside the iframe.")
        else:
            print("No iframes found on the page.")
      
        await asyncio.sleep(10)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
    finally:
        browser.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uc.loop().run_until_complete(website())

Error:
Error: 'NoneType' object is not callable
